# Is it possible to customize API Gateway custom authorizer response message and status code on unauthorized?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How do I set the status code to 429 and return a custom message from an API Gateway custom authorizer?

Answer (score 6):

The functionality here is a bit limited. But I've found that by editing the `Gateway Responses` for the 403 and 401 status codes. My custom message gets shown to users.

For example, by saving the below and re-deploying the API. I now get my custom message when the lambda authorizer returns a deny policy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Am also searching for this solution. i got messages like custom message & status code from our custom authorizer is not enabled.
refer here - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226689

But while coding for custom authorizer found that you can send either 401 or 403

```
//this will send status - 401 , body - {"message":"unauthorized"}    
context.fail('Unauthorized')

/*this will send status 403 , body - {
    "Message": "User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny"
}*/
context.succeed({
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:************/Development/*/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})

note : like allow you have to create deny policy
```